# Is there a limit for the number of propertyPages in a propertySheet?

Tags: winapi, mfc, dialog

In one of my [mfc](/questions/tagged/mfc) dialogs I use a propertySheet (with hidden tabs) to update subsections of the dialog during runtime. 
This works generally fine, but today I've hit a problem I can not find the reason to.

I'm adding propertyPages to the propertySheet in a simple for-loop:

```
m_myPropertySheet = new CMyPropertySheet();
long maxN = 50;
for ( long i=0; i<maxN; i++ )
{
  CMyPropPage * pMyPropPage = new CMyPropPage(i);
  m_myPropertySheet->AddPage( pMyPropPage );
}
```

and later I create that page using:

```
if(m_myPropertySheet->m_hWnd == NULL)
{   
  if  ( FALSE == m_myPropertySheet->Create(this, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, 0) )
    return;
}
```

This code works fine as long as I have less than 100 propertyPages in the sheet (i.e. `maxN<100` ), but once `maxN>=100` the `Create` call returns `FALSE`, and I do not quite understand why.

**Can somebody explain this?**

**Is there a limit of how many propertyPages I can have in a sheet?**

Comment: Look in the MFC sources, maybe you'll find something there. But maybe the 100 pages limit is defined in comctl32.dll. Anyway the 100 pages limit seems reasonable to me, because 100 pages is far more than any program would reasonably use.

Comment: BTW you don't need to add the pages that should not be visible. Instead of adding them and set them to invisible just don't add them in first pace. Or maybe I didn't understand everything in your question, you may add the reason why you need more than 100 pages.

Comment: @MichaelWalz Thx. Good suggestion. I can keep a vector of property-pages and just set them to the sheet on need. I'll try that. Also, it seems that 99 is indeed the limit, although all I could find online was [this link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/microsoft.public.vc.mfc/aJqGvFG6kqQ). I would still accept an answer which could point to the official information, though.

Comment: I don't have any official documentation, it's probably not officially documented.

Comment: When property sheet is created, there are options to create from `PROPSHEETPAGE` structures or from `HPROPSHEETPAGE` handles. You might want to try the other one (looking into MFC sources to find out the default behavior). I would say that if you experience problems at 100 pages then maybe it's internal API check/constraint and it treats larger values as invalid argument. Property sheets normally don't have 100 pages, of course. You might want to restructure your application to have no more than 100 per sheet.